# Can’t render webpage inside method

Tags: python, jinja2, webapp2

I am writing a GAE application (and using webapp2 framework and jinja2 as template renderer), and I wish to wrap all my GET and POST methods with a decorator. The decorator checks if the user has access to this page and if not, it should display an error message.

The problem is that, inside the decorator, I cannot use *self.response.write* to display an error message because the decorator is a method, it doesn’t ‘‘extend’’ webapp2.RequestHandler.

Here is the decorator code:

```
def checkpriv(classNo, errorMsg):
    def wrapFunction(method):
        if checkprivileges(classNo):
            return method
        else:
            logging.info(users.get_current_user().nickname() + errorMsg)
            # NEED TO DISPLAY ERROR MESSAGE HERE
    return wrapFunction
```

I tried to create a class that extends webapp2.RequestHandler and initialize an object of it inside the decorator but I get this Error 404 GET method is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a BaseHandler which overrides webapp2 init or dispatch. This way you do not need (or forget) a decorator.

Docs [init override](https://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/handlers.html#overriding-init) and [dispach override](https://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/handlers.html#overriding-dispatch).

I used dispatch override to create Role Based Access Control.

```
class BaseHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    """ webapp2 base handler """

    def dispatch:

        # abort or dispatch and pass an argument to the handler
        self.request.route_kwargs['user_access'] = UserAccess(self.request)
        super(BaseHandler, self).dispatch()


class YourHandler(BaseHandler):

    def get(self, user_access, ..):

        ....
```